# How do I update a plot generated on button push after abline input

Tags: r, shiny

let us say I have the app below (example code provided) that I would like to use for the following purposes:

- plot histogram of data
- set threshold for and add abline to the plot
- setting the threshold should generate a table with all the values above the threshold
- setting a new threshold would update the table, add a new abline to the plot and not make the plot disappear.

If you have any good tips I will be very grateful since I am getting my ears stuck in this Reactivity thing in Shiny.

````
data <- as.data.frame(iris3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput("ab", "Threshold", min = 0, max = 10, value = 2),
  
  actionBttn(color = "primary",
    inputId = "show",
    label = "Plot",
    style = "stretch",
    size = "lg"
  ),
  
  plotOutput("p"),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("t")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  plot <- eventReactive(input$show, {
    hist(data$`Sepal L..Versicolor`)
  })
  
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    plot()
    ab()
  })
  
  ab <- eventReactive(input$ab, {
    abline(h = input$ab)
  })
  
  output$t <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data[data$`Sepal L..Versicolor` > input$ab,]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)```
````

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with your program?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "Plot" button to update the abline, put abline inside `eventReactive()`:

```
data <- as.data.frame(iris3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput("ab", "Threshold", min = 0, max = 10, value = 2),
  
  actionButton(color = "primary",
             inputId = "show",
             label = "Plot",
             style = "stretch",
             size = "lg"
  ),
  
  plotOutput("p"),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("t")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  plot <- eventReactive(input$show, {
    hist(data$`Sepal L..Versicolor`)
    abline(h = input$ab, col = 'blue')
  })
  
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    plot()
    
  })
  
  output$t <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data[data$`Sepal L..Versicolor` > input$ab,]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

P.S. If the "Plot" button only update the abline, I would suggest you remove the button and use the slide bar to update the abline and table directly.

```
data <- as.data.frame(iris3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sliderInput("ab", "Threshold", min = 0, max = 10, value = 2),
  
  plotOutput("p"),
  
  DT::dataTableOutput("t")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  plot <- reactive({
    hist(data$`Sepal L..Versicolor`)
    abline(h = input$ab, col = 'blue')
  })
  
  output$p <- renderPlot({
    plot()
    
  })
  
  output$t <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data[data$`Sepal L..Versicolor` > input$ab,]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```